# Viewing Queue and Topic messages in WebSphere 6.1

Tags: jms, websphere, websphere-6.1, hermes-jms

I need to see the messages in Queues and Topics configured on WebSphere 6.1. I tried to configure HermesJMS, but just couldn't make it work. If someone knows how to make it work with WebSphere 6.1, it would be great!

Else... what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

By "configured on WebSphere 6.1", are you referring to queues / topics defined using WebSphere's default messaging provider (the internal one) or using a third-party JMS provider?

Also, if you let us know what errors you get when trying HermesJMS, perhaps we can help you out.

Isaac